# Laravel controller DI

Tags: php, laravel, oop, dependency-injection

I have a controller and FileUploader::class. Uploader injected to controller __construct method. When I'm using this injected instance in code (see bellow) I got the same obj each time. 
Whaen I've refactored class (see second pat of code) without using injected property - it works. But I want to follow the same style across the project.

When it was one file upload, it worked fine, but for multiple file upload solution, with a loop, it not works.

```
class ProposalFileController extends Controller
{
    public $fileUploader;

    public function __construct(FileUploader $fileUploader)
    {
        $this->fileUploader = $fileUploader;
    }

    public function upload(ProposalFileUpload $request)
    {
        $files = [];

        foreach ($request->file('files') as $file)
        {

            /** !!! Attention here !!!!!!!
               In this loop, $this->fileUploader is same obj each time 
             **/
            $files[] = $this->fileUploader->upload($file);
        }

        return response()
            ->json([
               'data' => $files
            ]);
    }
}
```

I need new uploader instance each time. The class bellow works, but I don't like it style. How can I solve it with DI solution?

```
class ProposalFileController extends Controller
{
    public $fileUploader;

    public function __construct(FileUploader $fileUploader)
    {
        $this->fileUploader = $fileUploader;
    }

    public function upload(ProposalFileUpload $request)
    {
        $files = [];

        foreach ($request->file('files') as $file)
        {
            $uploader = new FileUploader(new File());
            $files[] = $uploader->upload($file);
        }

        return response()
            ->json([
               'data' => $files
            ]);
    }
}
```

FileUpload::class

```
class FileUploader implements Uploader
{
    use UploadHelper;

    private $file;

    public function __construct(File $file)
    {
        $this->file = $file;
    }

    public function upload(UploadedFile $file)
    {
        $saveName = $this->fileName($file);

        /** Save file to s3 */
        $storagePath = Storage::disk('s3')->put(...);

        /** Set cover_rel - relative path needed for delete file needs */
        $this->file->setAttribute('file_rel', $storagePath);

        $this->file->save();

        return $this->file;
    }
}
```

In the end, I've got array with same File n-times (same with loop steps)

Comment: In FileUploader::class File::class is also injected in __construct() method.

Comment: It looks like the issue here lies within your FileUploader class, why must you make a new instance for each file. Would it not be possible to restructure this class so that is not necessary?

Comment: @Josh will add a FileUploadClass

Comment: @Josh take a look please

Answer (score 0):

You can inject an instance of FileUploader in your loop using the `app` method as below

`$uploader = app(FileUploader::class)`

Comment: It's not looks like DI... 
It's almost same with my second variant, just more 'in-laravel-way' ... 

I want to use ` $this->fileUploader->upload(...) `